# How should I be thinking about the total derivative at a point?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus

I am curious as to how I should be reasoning about the total derivative of a function when evaluated at a point. I have been thinking of these objects as linear functions, which it seems to me that they are. However I just happened across the following problem which suggests that I should instead be thinking of them in the same way I think of matrices:

Say I have two functions $f$ and $g$ such that

$$g, f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$$

Now, if $\chi$ is a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ we see that

$$Dg(\chi), Df(\chi) \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$$

are linear transformations. Now, if $v$ is another vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ I wonder how I should interpret the expression

$$[Dg(\chi)\cdot Df(\chi)](v)$$

For, if I think of $Dg(\chi)$ and $Df(\chi)$ as matrices, we have that

$$[Dg(\chi)\cdot Df(\chi)](v) = Dg(\chi)(Df(\chi)(v))$$

(ie a composition of functions). If I instead regard them as linear functions then I should have

$$[Dg(\chi)\cdot Df(\chi)](v) = Dg(\chi)(v) \cdot Df(\chi)(v)$$

which doesn't make sense.

It seems to me that the notation is vague. Of course it may just be that I am being dense. How should I reason with these derivatives?

I apologise if the question is somewhat vague. Feel free to add the (soft-question) if it is necessary.

Comment: don't you think of matrices the same way you do about linear transformation? The total derivative can and should be thought of as a linear transformation.

Comment: The derivative can be thought of as a linear transformation whose basis representation is in the form of a matrix.

Comment: @IttayWeiss The real source of my confusion is the handling of multiplication as above. I have learnt that when we are thinking of functions $f$ and $g$ we have $(f\cdot g)(x) = f(x) \cdot g(x)$, which is not generalising to functions with values in dimension > 1.

Comment: True, not everything true for derivatives in dimension one holds for functions of more variables.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Am I supposed to think of multiplication of linear functions as composition in higher dimensions and as point-wise multiplication in 1-dimension and not be concerned by this inconsistency?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that. In any case, functions $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ can be multiplied, but functions $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$, for $n>1$, can't. It's a fact of life that has little to do with how to think about derivatives.

Comment: @IttayWeiss My issue was that the same notation could mean different things in different contexts. Namely if $f, g$ are functions $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ then $(g\cdot f)(x) = g(x) \cdot f(x)$, whereas if they are linear functions with $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ and $g\colon \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ then $(g\cdot f)(x) = g(f(x))$. I thought it to be a bit ambiguous is all.

Comment: $\cdot$ means multiplication, but $\circ $ is used for composition.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Yes, I know. I was reading a book and they used $\cdot$ to mean an operation like this: $(Dg(f(\chi)) \cdot Df(\chi))(v) = Dg(f(\chi))(Df(\chi)(v))$. I thought this notation was ambiguous, for I thought it could also mean $Dg(f(\chi))(v)\cdot Df(\chi)(v)$ which is nonsense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wonder how I should interpret the expression $[Dg(\chi)\cdot Df(\chi)](v)$

I think it's best to not try to interpret it at all. It's a  unnatural  expression without an intrinsic meaning.

Multiplication of matrices is composition of linear operators. The linear operators $Df(\chi)$   and $Dg(\chi)$ are both defined in the same copy of $\mathbb R^n$ (the domain of $f$ and $g$) and go from there to the second copy of $\mathbb R^n$, in which $f$ and $g$ take values. Their composition does not make real sense (although it's formally defined as a product of matrices).

On the other hand, if we are in the situation of the chain rule - the domain of $g$ contains the range of $f$ - then the product of $Dg(f(\chi))$ with $Df(\chi)$  makes sense: it's the composition of linear operators.  We have three copies of $\mathbb R^n$ in this situation: $f$ goes from first to second, $g$ from second to third.

It is important to keep in mind the distinction between different copies of $\mathbb R^n$. Doing  calculus on manifolds enforces this distinction: if $f$ and $g$ are smooth maps from manifold $M$ to manifold $N$, there is no way to multiply $Df$ and $Dg$.

---

On the third hand, if we are talking about maps between Riemannian manifolds (which include $\mathbb R^n$ with their standard metric), then one can take the *scalar product* of $Df(\chi)$ and $Dg(\chi)$. It is usually defined as $\langle A,B \rangle =\operatorname{tr}( B^TA)$ where $A$ and $B$ are matrices (such as $Df(\chi)$ and $Dg(\chi)$). This product generalizes $f'(x)g'(x)$ from one-dimensional analysis.

Comment: This was a very helpful answer. Thanks.